# need help in linking with wikipedia viewer

Tags: jquery, ajax, anchor

when i click the heading i want to go to relevant wikipedia article.i tried the wrap method.But it isn't happening.please help.
Here is the code.

```
$(function(){
$('#bar').click(function(){
  $('#bar').hide().fadeOut(1000);
  $('#search_box').show().fadeIn(2000).focus();
  $('a,p').hide();
  $('.btn').show();
});
  $('#clear').click(function(){
    $('#search_box').val('');
  });
  $('#search_box').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13)
      {
        getData();
      }
  });

  $('#search').click(function(){
    getData();
  });

  function getData()
  {
    $('.title ,.card').remove();
    var searchQuery = $('#search_box').val();
    $.getJSON('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&list=search&srsearch='+searchQuery+'&utf8&callback=?', function(data){
      console.log(data);
      var query = data.query.search;

      for(var i=0;i<query.length;i++)
        {

        **$('<div class="title">'+query[i].title+'</div>').addClass('title').wrap('<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"'+encodeURIComponent(query[i].title)+'"> </a>').appendTo('body');**


  $('<div>'+query[i].snippet+'</div>').appendTo('body').addClass('card');;

        }

});
  }
});
```

And here is a link to my pen.
http://codepen.io/R_Ganesh/pen/eBBmwW

Comment: I want to link the heading in the results to the respective wiki pages

Comment: You're ending the double quotes too soon in your `wrap()`  I don't think that's the only problem, but it's definitely going to cause you problems. `/wiki/"'+encodeURIComponent` should be `/wiki/'+encodeURIComponent`

Comment: It isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.wrapInner()` method to wrap link inside `div` element

```
$('<div class="title"></div>')
.wrapInner("<a href='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+encodeURIComponent(query[i].title)+"'>"+query[i].title+"</a>")
.appendTo('body');
```

in your `.wrap()` method your link doesn't have any value.

```
.wrap('<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'+encodeURIComponent(query[i].title)+'"> </a>')
                                                                                     ^
```

Add `query[i].title` value to link. And with `wrapInner()` wrap that link around the `<div class="title">` content

Check working code:
[codePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vygLOZ)

Comment: Thanks for explaining dude .